# Is it possible to change timezone in jevents?

Tags: joomla

Is it possible to change timezone in `jevents` calendar Joomla? And, whenever timezone changes one timezone to other timezone then date automatically convert and place in the correct calendar cell.

Answer (score 0):

JEvents stores the events based on a timezone as it is iCal based. So yes it is possible.

When you import/export events this is also configurable via the JEvents -> Configuration -> iCal Import/Export.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about it but may it's help to you.

Click Here [jEvent](https://www.jevents.net/forum/faq.php#f1r1)